# windows 8 winform won't autostart when requestedExecutionLevel set to "requireAdministrator"

Tags: c#, windows, permissions, autostart

i created a winform application.

my program needs **administrator permissions** to work, 
so i added **app.manifest** file with the following privileges:

```
<requestedPrivileges xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
</requestedPrivileges>
```

i added the program to the windows 8 autostart so it should autostart.
when i change the app.manifest to the following line, it loads successfully at start of windows.

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />
```

how can i start my program with windows and still keep its administrator permission?

thanks,
shlomi

Comment: This is specifically disabled in Windows.  The user has no idea where the UAC prompt might come from right after logging in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either separate the functionality that needs high privileges and put it in a Windows Service (you can set the account under which the server starts or the SYSTEM account by default). OR start your application using scheduled tasks (here you can also choose the account/privileges under which your application runs)

Comment: if i want to create a windows service also, can it be under the same solution and also under the same setup?

Comment: @ShlomiKomemi Yes, you can add a Windows Service project to your existing solution.