# C# windows application failed to auto run on window restart

Tags: c#

I have created a msi setup of my C# windows form application. My application need administrator permissions to run some functionality so I use following code in my app.manifest file:

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

I also add registry key to run my application every time when system start.

The above line of code restrict my application to auto run.

On the other hand, when I change level="requireAdministrator" to "asInvoker" then my application works properly.

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />
```

Comment: Can't see any question here...

Comment: What happens when it's run from the registry?

Comment: I want to auto run my application with level="requireAdministrator"

Comment: Take a look [here](https://superuser.com/questions/46/elevated-priviliges-for-startup-applications-in-windows)

Comment: @BaliC It works when run from the registry.

Comment: The TaskScheduler will most likely be the solution

Comment: Possible duplicate of [windows 8 winform won't autostart when requestedExecutionLevel set to "requireAdministrator"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12875371/windows-8-winform-wont-autostart-when-requestedexecutionlevel-set-to-requiread)